# ReactJS - How to change state of child by id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have a parent component which is created through using another component by iterating over a for loop n number of times, and an id is assigned to each child.

**Now, I need to change the state of each child from within the parent. But each individual piece has to be changed one at a time, depending on the input.**

**How can I achieve this? Do I have to declare n number of state variables?**

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [color1, setColor1] = useState('yellow')
  const [color2, setColor2] = useState('yellow')

  function updateState1 () {
    setColor1('red')
  }

  function updateState2 () {
    setColor2('red')
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>Parent</div>
      <Child childState={color1} updateState={updateState1} id='1' />
      <Child childState={color2} updateState={updateState2} id='2' />
    </>
  )
}
```

Below is the child component. I understand that the id is not doing anything here.
I want to be able to just have one function through which I can pass the id of the button I want to target
and the color i want to set it to.

```
const btnStyle = {
  backgroundColor: 'green'
}

const Child = ({ childState, updateState, id, targetButton }) => {
  
  function handleClick () {
    updateState()
  }
  
  return (
    <button id={id} style={((childState === null) && a==id) ? btnStyle: {"backgroundColor":childState}} onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array or an object to store the state values for each child component and pass a function from the parent component to the child component that can update the state value based on the `id` or `index` of the child component.

For example:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Child = ({ color, updateColor }) => {
  function handleClick() {
    updateColor("red");
  }

  return (
    <button style={{ backgroundColor: color }} onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  );
};

export default function Parent() {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(["yellow", "yellow"]);

  function updateColor(index, color) {
    const newColors = [...colors];
    newColors[index] = color;
    setColors(newColors);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>Parent</div>
      <Child color={colors[0]} updateColor={(color) => updateColor(0, color)} />
      <Child color={colors[1]} updateColor={(color) => updateColor(1, color)} />
    </>
  );
}
```

---

## UPDATED ANSWER

If you have a lot of data, you can use `map` method.

For example

```
{colors.map((color, index) => (
  <Child
    key={`child-color-${index}`}
    color={color}
    updateColor={(color) => updateColor(index, color)}
  />
))}
```

You can see the result of this example here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bohr-f5mm8h?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Is there are way to not implement each child component one at a time? Because I have 40 components I need to update, not only 2.

Comment: You can use an array iterator such as `map`. I updated my answer. please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Make the child as simple as possible, and control the state and the state change in the parent:

```js
const { useState, Fragment } = React

const defaultColor = 'yellow';

const Child = ({ color, handleClick }) => (
  <button style={{ backgroundColor: color }} onClick={handleClick}>
    Click me
  </button>
)

const Parent = () => {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState({})

  function setColor(id) {
    setColors(prev => {     
      return { 
        ...prev, 
        [id]: !prev[id] || prev[id] === defaultColor 
          ? 'red'
          : defaultColor
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>Parent</div>
      {Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, id) => (
        <Child 
          key={id}
          color={colors[id] || defaultColor} 
          handleClick={() => setColor(id)} />
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Parent />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```